"Export to Excel" Exporting only a single filename
I want to export the contents of the default document library with SP online. I'm able to do so with a small site of which I'm the owner, but in a larger site on which I've tested this capability with full administrator privileges I get only a single row, always the same Word file, yet there are several thousand documents in the library.  I've tried several things without success:

Looking at only a single subfolder produces an empty export, except when using the folder containing that Word file.
Adding files to other folders still produces the same single file output when attempting to export from the full document library.  I assume this means that the problem is not a result of the number of documents.
Moving the Word file to another folder still produces that single row with that same file when searching the full library.
Creating a new view and filtering it to only a few dates, then exporting still produces the single-row excel file with that Word file, even though it's not in that date range.
So far as I can tell there is nothing special about the filename: 20210413 LRSP Agenda.docx.  It opens, edits and saves normally.
I receive no error messages when performing the export.

I welcome suggestions.

Troubleshooting Export Issues in SharePoint Online Document Library
Hey there! Here are steps to resolve your export issue:
Ensure Permissions: Verify you have sufficient permissions for the document library, including administrative rights if needed.
Check Library View: Ensure the view used for export includes all documents without filters that could restrict output.
Test with Different Files: Export from various folders or files to rule out specific file issues affecting export.
Review Export Settings: Double-check export settings to confirm they capture all document metadata and content.
Consult SharePoint Support: If issues persist, contact Microsoft support for deeper troubleshooting tailored to SharePoint Online specifics.
These steps should help pinpoint and resolve the export problem effectively.
